# Query that will apply to EVERY SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, drop-database

I'm testing a drop database query for all databases that begin with a specific prefix. However, because that can easily lead to horrific things I'm taking my drop database query

```
declare @dbname nvarchar (200);
declare @query nvarchar (max);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select name from sys.databases 
where name like 'PREFIX%' 

Open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
  set @query = 'Drop Database ['+ @dbname + ']' 
  Exec(@query)

  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END
Close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

and want to change the `Drop Database` part to something that is less scary.

So **MAIN QUESTION** is there a simple SQL query that I could put in there that would always apply to any SQL Server database? So I know that this query will only affect the databases I want it to before switching it back to `Drop Database`?

**EDIT:** Better yet, a query that will return the names of the databases. 
Like `select name from sys.databases` but one that will work with `['+ @dbname + ']` to return only the names of databases with that prefix to ensure that this query affects the appropriate databases.

Comment: use database will apply. But I am not sure how will it help

Comment: @lazy See edit I made

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use a cursor here?

Comment: Just `PRINT` instead of `Exec`. And use `QUOTENAME` not homemade square bracket addition.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Exec(@query)`, just call `PRINT @query`.  That will show you the SQL that you intend to run.

[PRINT Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First of all just execute the following query and it will tell you what databases will it bring forward in the rest of the code

```
select name from sys.databases 
where name like 'PREFIX%'
```

Finally add a `PRINT` statement to see the final `DROP DATABASE` statements dynamically build inside the cursor.

Some minor improvement in your code:

```
declare @dbname  SYSNAME;
declare @query nvarchar (max);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR  
select name from sys.databases 
where name like 'PREFIX%' 

Open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

  set @query = 'Drop Database '+ QUOTENAME(@dbname)  

   --Exec sp_executesql @query       --<-- For execution
   -- PRINT @query                   --<-- For debugging
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END
Close db_cursor

deallocate db_cursor
```